File ownership on a samba or nfs share client
How is file ownership dealt with within a samba or nfs share on the client side (ie the file owner the client actually sees)
I realise that ownership on the host system can be forced (on Samba at least) through the config, but what if I wanted to share a large data volume from an nfs or samba server (I'm open to using either) but inside that share on the client end there needs to be various different owners of files and folders? Is this possible?
For reasons too long to go into, I want to move my main data storage off a server I've been running for some time.
Within this are files that are owned by www-data (nextcloud data folder), will (me), media (a plex data folder) and cctv (a recording store for cameras)
Is there an easy way to maintain an ownership structure like this within a shared storage, or would I be better off breaking each of the folders down into separate shares and mounting them individually?
The content of the storage will remain as-is, I'm currently cloning the entire machine that's currently handling the storage (including the actual storage image) and plan on setting up an open media vault vm that will solely host the storage and share it back to the cloned vm for testing and setup. I would hope to continue to have the existing vm host the shares (in a kind of network share inception setup) until I can update all the clients to pull the shares directly from the new omv shares.
I hope that all makes sense.

inside that share on the client end there needs to be various different owners of files and folders? Is this possible? possible? it's the default. Depends on the file system, but nearly all actual SMB file server implementations the owner of the file or directory is stored in the file or directory object itself. That means every single file and directory can be assigned a different owner. The other things that you mention, such as specifying the identity for created files are to compensate for when the design structure has failed.

So I could, say, mount a samba share at /home at boot and the user folders within it would have the correct permissions on the client system?

If clients come from different hosts (you, next cloud, etc.), you can configure them to use dedicated export (NFS) that enforce a specific uid/gid.
